# \verb and align

Tags: verbatim

I am getting an error when I am using the verb command in align.

I prefer not to use \texttt because the underscore isn't the right length for a single underscore or a double underscore - the right length is somewhere in the middle.

Here's my code:

```
\begin{align}
    \Verb|Phot_Flag| 0 \\
    \Verb{class_star} > 0.9
\end{align}
```

Comment: please post a fully compilable MWE.

Comment: You should get the same underscore in verb or texttt

Comment: Which error do you get? Check the log file.

Answer (score 3):

There is an `examplep` package you can use.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{examplep}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \PVerb{Phot_Flag } 0 \\
    \PVerb{class_star} > 0.9
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

You just need to detokenize the input, if all you want is being able to use `_`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\vtt}[1]{%
  \text{\normalfont\ttfamily\detokenize{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\vtt{Phot_Flag}  &= 0 \\
\vtt{class_star} &> 0.9
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `verbatimbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{myverbbox}{\PF}Phot_Flag\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}{\CS}class_star\end{myverbbox}
\begin{align}
    \PF &= 0 \\
    \CS &> 0.9
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also give optional directives to the verb boxes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox,amsmath,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{myverbbox}[\scriptsize]{\PF}Phot_Flag\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}[\itshape]{\CS}class_star\end{myverbbox}
\begin{align}
    \PF &= 0 \\
    \CS &> 0.9
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]